# Distance Transform on Canny Edge Detected Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi I am trying to obtain a distance transform  to an endge image and I want to obtain similar results in given figures
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo2U9.png)   [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa34r.png)

```py
import cv2 
img = cv2.imshow("image.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Applying the Canny Edge filter
edge = cv2.Canny(img, t_lower, t_upper)
#dil = cv2.dilate(edge,(3,3),iterations=20)
distTransform=cv2.distanceTransform(edge,cv2.DIST_L1,5)
```

However, openCV canny edge detection function gives me 1px thick edges, so the output of distance tranform becomes same as the input.
[Figure 3 - Distance transform to edge detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26PRL.png)
Dilating the edge works good however, I don't want to cause a change in the image. How can i obtain similar resuts as in figure 1 and 2?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Afair, distanceTransform assumes "active" pixels to be value 0, so use the inverse of canny edge result instead. edge = 255 - canny

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trying I have found that the distance transform function in OpenCV works differently than the Matlab one. OpenCV one assumes active pixels to be value 0 as @Micka said. Shifting the input is a choice. However, I also found a custom function which also works great in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678520/speed-up-computation-for-distance-transform-on-image-in-python) post.